# What is the difference between int `*p = new int(5);` and `int *p = new int[5];`

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

I just need to understand what the differences between these are:

```
int *p = new int[5];
```

and

```
int *p = new int(5);
```

Comment: an array of 5 un-initialized ints vs 1 int initialized to 5

Comment: The difference is you shouldn't use either of them in modern C++ code. Instead use `std::vector` or some other kind of Standard Library container.

Answer (score 10):

One creates an array of five `int`s and assigns a pointer to this array's first element to `p`. None of the integers in this array are initialized:

```
int *p = new int[5]; // a pointer to an array of 5 integers
```

The other one creates a single `int`, and assigns a pointer to that `int` to `p`. This integer is initialized with `5`:

```
int *p = new int(5); // a pointer to an int
```

As [tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87189/tadman) points out in his comment, in essence, the difference is between the [`operator new` and `operator new[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new). `new[]` allocates an array and *must* be deleted with `delete[]`, while `new` allocates a single object and must be deleted with `delete`. If you delete with the wrong operator, what happens is undefined behavior. Of course, unless you are a library implementer, you should *generally* prefer smart pointers and library containers over `new` and `new[]`.

Comment: Important lesson here is the difference between [`operator new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) and `operator new[]`.